# error: waitpid for fetch-pack failed: No child processes

Tags: windows, git, github, cmd

I am getting this error when trying to clone any repository.

cant find much help on this from google.

```
C:\wamp64\www>git clone https://github.com/codeg8/laravel-crud-generator.git
Cloning into 'laravel-crud-generator'...
remote: Counting objects: 50, done.
remote: Total 50 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 50
Unpacking objects: 100% (50/50), done.
error: waitpid for fetch-pack failed: No child processes
```

Answer (score 22):

Try running Git application as an Administrator (right click-> Run as Administrator), if its Windows. 
It worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Run the Git Bash as admin and clone the directly.
I had the same issue and above solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This was a problem with the version of Git Installed on my system. I was using an older version of Git.

If anyone is facing the same issue, try upgrading your git installation to latest version. This solved my issue.

Comment: This didnt work for me - i was using the latest git. however using `tortoise for git` windows client instead of git gui/git bash worked